# UIActivityIndicator on UITableViewCell's UIImageView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to add a `UIActivityIndicator` to a `UITableViewCell`'s `UIImageView`. For some reason, it will not show up unless make my own custom cell and image view. Does anyone know why the standard `UITableViewCell` will not show a `UIActivityIndicator`?

I have tried all the obvious things: color, frame, etc...

```
activationInProgressIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

[cell.imageView addSubview:activationInProgressIndicator];

[activationInProgressIndicator startAnimating];
```

Comment: WHY on earth are you adding an activity indicator to your cell? (Oh I suppose if you're waiting for an image, you add an activity indicator? )

Comment: I am waiting to notify the user if a request was successful or not.

Comment: And that should be done in the a table view cell? o.O

Comment: Yes, it should be done in the cell. You seem to think you know a lot about an application you have never seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the frame of the UIImageView is zero if there is not an image in it. I added a transparent image to the image view and then added the activity indicator as a subview. That works well. But it is not the best solution. It is probably better to just add the UIActivityIndicatorView directly to the cell.